# Fixing an infinite loop when taking a user input in Java

Tags: java, loops, validation, input, infinite-loop

I've been writing my first Java script and have ran into an issue. I do not understand why when this is ran the program waits for the user to input something on the first time the loop runs, then the input is dealt with and the corresponding response is made, but the second time it runs it gets stuck in an infinite loop without waiting for the user's input. For the record, I do want this to be an infinite loop, except that the program should end if the user enters "3". If after each case I write "keep_going = false;" the program functions, but doesn't keep looping, obviously. All help is appreciated, thanks!

```
import java.io.*; 

class Choice
{ 
public static void main (String[] args) 
{  
    String input = ""; 
    Boolean keep_going = true;
    while (keep_going)
    {
        input = "";
        System.out.println("Welcome to my program! Would you like to:");
        System.out.println("1. Say hi.");
        System.out.println("2. Find out my favourite colour.");
        System.out.println("3. End the program.");
        System.out.println(">");
        System.out.print( "> " );
        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader( System.in );
        BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader( isr );
        try
        { 
            input = buffer.readLine();
            buffer.close() ; 
        } 
        catch (IOException e ) 
        { 
            System.out.println(e);  
        } 
        switch (input)
        {
            case "1": System.out.println("Hi!"); break;
            case "2": System.out.println("My favourite colour is blue!"); break;
            case "3": return;
            default : System.out.println(input + " is not a valid option. Please try again.");
        }
    }


}
```

}

Comment: You shouldn't be closing `buffer`, and certainly not in the loop. Move the reader, buffer etc before the loop.

Comment: `"For the record, I do want this to be an infinite loop, except that the program should end if the user enters "3". "` -- then only set keep_going false in `case "3":`, right? Also, yes, do not keep opening and closing the buffer. Open it before the loop, close it after.

Comment: Could you please explain as to why I should move these things to outside the buffer and what they actually mean? I'm just new to this. Thanks!

Comment: FYI:  Lots of good examples of program input on the beginner questions in www.hackerrank.com site.

Comment: @djangofan it is very useful.

Answer (score 0):

the infinite loop was due to line `buffer.close() ;`

Make this adjustments

1. remove `buffer.close() ;`

   `//buffer.close() ;`
2. `case "3": keep_going=false;break;`